# GHC.Prim.Any's created instead of free variable [in polymorphic function]

Tags: haskell, field, ghc

Is this a bug?

```
{-# LANGUAGE NoMonomorphismRestriction #-}
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.Language (haskellDef)
(P.TokenParser { P.identifier = ident }) = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef
```

yields `ident` of type `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT String GHC.Prim.Any Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String`, whereas defining

```
haskell = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef
ident = P.identifier haskell
```

yields one of type `Text.Parsec.Prim.ParsecT String u Data.Functor.Identity.Identity String`

#### edit

The behavior is not identical in ghci,

```
infixl 4 <++>
(<++>) = liftM2 (++)

(P.TokenParser { P.identifier = ident }) = P.makeTokenParser haskellDef
suitable_macro = ident

parseMacro = many space *> suitable_macro

parseMacro' =
    try (string "{{" *> parseMacro <* string "}}")

parseAll = many (noneOf "{") <++>
    option "" (parseMacro' <|> (string "{" <++> parseAll))
```

Then, try to run it,

```
*Hz2.Preproc> parseTest parseAll "asdf{{b}}"

<interactive>:0:11:
    Couldn't match expected type `()' with actual type `GHC.Prim.Any'
    Expected type: Parsec String () a0
    Actual type: ParsecT
                    String GHC.Prim.Any Data.Functor.Identity.Identity [Char]
    In the first argument of `parseTest', namely `parseAll'
    In the expression: parseTest parseAll "asdf{{b}}"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not really; I believe it's Report-compliant behaviour: fully polymorphic type variables in patterns are instantiated to `Any`. However, in GHC 7.2 onwards, this [works like you'd expect](http://hackage.haskell.org/trac/ghc/ticket/2357) (see especially the commit message at the end).

As for the GHCi behaviour, this is because GHCi's [extended defaulting rules](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) default fully-polymorphic variables to `()`.